# Find the limit of the function:$f(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}-\sin x$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

I have here an exercise which says: find the limit to $-\infty$ of

$$f(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}-\sin x.$$

Here in my book it's shown the solution and it is said, because:

$$x-\frac{x^3}{6}-\sin x\ge x-\frac{x^3}{6}-1,$$

then we have that

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty} x-\frac{x^3}{6}-1 = +\infty,$$

so

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)=+\infty$$

> I do not understand why 
>   $$x-\frac{x^3}{6}-\sin x\ge x-\frac{x^3}{6}-1,$$
>   and in general what principle or method was used to solve this exercise.

I hope you'll explain me. Thank you!!!

Comment: You understand that $\sin{x}\leq 1$ for all $x$ right?

Comment: Yes I know that

Comment: Please don't use `$$ .. $$` in the title of your question. It f\*\*ks up the rendering of the front page. Also, punctuation should go *inside* the display math (e.g. `$$f(x) = x,$$`) otherwise you get dangling commas and full stops on the line after the math which just looks stupid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intuitively, we know that
$$\sin x\le 1\tag1$$
then adding both sides $(1)$ with $\dfrac{x^3}6-x$, yield
$$
\dfrac{x^3}6-x+\sin x\le\dfrac{x^3}6-x+1.\tag2
$$
Now, multiply both sides $(2)$ with $-1$, yield
$$
x-\dfrac{x^3}6-\sin x\ge x-\dfrac{x^3}6-1.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$-1 \le \sin x \le 1$, so you can replace the $\sin x$ term with a constant and change the equality to an inequality. This leaves you having to only evaluate the limit of a cubic, rather than the sum of a cubic and a trig function.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  $|\sin x|\leq 1$ always right ? now so and since $x-\dfrac{x^{3}}{6}$ negative and note $x^{3}$ is highest power goes to $-\infty$ so inequality holds. I hope it will help you to understand now.